# How to change /blog url to some other url in Magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, header

How to change /blog url to some other url in Magento 1.9.2
     I want to redirect request at  http://www.xxxx.com/modular to  http://www.xxxx.com/blog/modular

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do url rewriting from magento admin panel by **following below steps :**

1. Logged into magento admin then click on Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management
2. To add new url rewrite rule Click on Add Url rewrite. Select custom
   if you want to used it as custom url rewrite.**(Ex here Request url
   -http://www.xxxx.com/blog and target url - http://www.xxxx.com/modular)**
3. Then add request url (source url) and target url (desitnation url)
   click on save.
4. Check it will works.

Answer (score 1):

You can add url rewrite from admin :

Admin -> Catalog -> URL Rewrite Management

Click on button "Add URL Rewrite" select "custom: in Create URL Rewrite.

you can add your request url and target ur as you want.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be done with htaccess

Redirect 301 /modular http://www.xxxx.com/blog/modular